# how to reload an opened tab bar in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

my application has three tabs. In tab 1 a view controller lets the user add the name of a contact to tab 2 (A button does this task). As soon as the button is pressed the name gets added to tab 2 and the button is disabled for future operations.

But when the user deletes the name from tab 2 the button should be enabled again. I am able to do this if i reload the tab 1 through the navigation controller but if i switch to tab 1 from 2 the button is still disabled even after the user has deleted the name from tab 2.

how to refresh tab 1 when the user has deleted the name in tab 2

Comment: Hey KPO... You can add the checking in viewWillAppear of tab1 viewController. WillDidLoad will be called only once in tab bar controller.

Comment: provide some codes first and let us know where you called your method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Your tab 1 VC from tab 2 VC by TabbarController. and enable the button after deleting the data .

```
    if let tabbarControllers = self.tabBarController?.childViewControllers {
        if let firstController = tabbarControllers[0] as? YourFirstVC {
              firstController.yourButtonOutlet.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         }
   }
```

And if your tab 1 vc embeded in a navigationcontroller then use.

```
if let tabbarControllers = self.tabBarController?.childViewControllers {
    if let firstControllersNavigation = tabbarControllers[0] as? UINavigationController {
        if let firstController = firstControllersNavigation.childViewControllers[0] as? YourFirstVC {
           firstController.yourButtonOutlet.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
     }
}
```